# How might I wire a split pi converter to transistors as to maximize output voltage?

Tags: frequency, dc-dc-converter, boost, duty-cycle, switch-mode-power-supply

I was looking into various dc-dc converter designs, and I was interested in the [split pi converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-pi_topology).
[image: a busy cat]

As a start, I just want to maximize the output voltage. I know in theory, the output voltage could be infinite, and in practice, it will be limited all the imperfections of the components I use. For now, I am just trying to better understand of how dc converters work. I have a basic understanding of how the buck and boost converters work, but I would really like to get a firm grasp on the split pi.

Also, would it be possible to get the same power transfer with BJTs as opposed to mosfets?

---100% speculation below this line---

I suspect there ought to be an optimum frequency that the transistors oscillate based on the capacitors and inductors used. I also suspect given an optimum transistor configuration, replacing some wires to the gates/bases of the transistors with resistors will yield an optimum configuration for for an arbitrary gain between input and output voltages. I also suspect that the ratio between certain pairs of these resistors will determine the gain of the system.

Comment: No, I am not going to chase down a link.  Post a schematic of the relevant parts.

Comment: Ok I added a picture.

Comment: I thought the split pi was patented (GB2376357B). A ridiculous patent, no less. Sticking a buck converter on the output of a boost converter is not novel or unique; it shouldn't qualify for a patent.

Comment: 9 years later, that patent has now expired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summarised Solution:**

Over 1 kV out from say 5 to 12V in if optimised for this purpose and your switches and output capacitor can handle it.

In real use, a few hundred volts would be doable but more than was sensible.

**Long:**

The split Pi is more complex than you need for what you say you want.
 This is essentially a synchronous input, synchronous output full bridge boost buck converter used in many modern designs. It is fully bidirectional - ie it will convert any voltage at left to any sensible voltage at right OR can convert equally well in the reverse direction.

All you need to start is the parts up to C3. This is a standard boost converter. In non-synchronous versions S2 is replaced with an "upwards pointing" diode.  (Parts to right of C3 will down convert the voltage on C3).

The available output voltage is "heaps" but in practice if maximum voltage was an aim you would place a second winding on L1 to provide a stepup ratio.

In real world use you could convert from say 12V to hundreds of volts as shown if necessary. The usual limits are the voltage ratings of L1, S1, S2, C3 (ignoring components beyond that).
 In extreme cases the interwinding breakdown voltage if L1 becomes important (ask me how I know :-) ) with the voltage at the start of one winding and the end of the next being two layer voltages apart when windings are layed successively right to left then left to right. In some cases the voltage towards the winding ends can exceed the breakdown voltage of the wire insulation - making interwinding insulation  important and how the wires are handled mechanically at the ends of each layer important. In most cases this is not an issue.

The absolute maximum output voltage occurs when the inductive energy in L1 is transferred into its stray capacitance. Consider:
 Open all switches.
 Close S1 until I in L1 is at a max.
 Open S1 and DO NOT close any switch.
 Voltage on L1 will now "ring" positively until the 0.5 x L1 x I^2 energy is stored in stray capacitance of L1 as 0.5 x Cstray x Vring^2.
 So

- Vring_max = sqrt ( L1 x I^2 / Cstray)

With 12V in (or almost an Vin as Iin_max is what counts) this could be more than 1 kV in a carefully optimised case.
 S1 and S2 are liable to object in most cases.

Comment: I know the split pi is more complex than what I said I want. However, I was going to try to figure out how to get an arbitrary gain once I got maximum gain.

Comment: It was difficult to capture on falstad's circuit simulator, but your design does seem to produce a very short voltage spike as soon as I close the switch. Part of the reason I wanted to use the split pi rather than a simple boost is that I thought it might be easier to maintain that high voltage with more switching control. Is there a way to maintain this high voltage with the right switching configuration?

Comment: Spike "shortness" and magnitude depends on energy available and capacitor it is transferred into and any resistance. Second half of circuit is a buck converter which steps the voltage DOWN again. "Maintaining" the voltage depends entirely on how fast you take energy out of the C3 store. In an ideal circuit C3 will maintain whatever V it acquires forever if all switches are open. "Gain" has no obvious meaning here. || Energy out = energy in over time in the real world. To "maintain" voltage energy must come in and not leave. Energy out can be by losses or intentionally.

Comment: This just comes down to conservation of energy at each time--i.e power. So the energy can either be pulsed out quickly, or drained out slowly. So you could maintain the voltage--but you would have to decrease the hight of the spike. Right?

Comment: More or less, yes. ie you cannot "maintain" any given voltage on a capacitor if you remove energy but you can vary it minimally by removing minimal energy. IF constant Vout is an aim then the 2nd half of uoir circuit becomes useful.- boost with left half to some voltage and then buck convert with right half to some lower voltage. As long as V_C3 > Vout you get constant voltage. BUT just running the boost converter at constant Vout does the same.